# Google Chrome Extension using WebNavigation API

Tags: api, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I would like to known if the webNavigation API is still experimental, because I need to use chrome.experimental.webNavigation.onBeforeNavigate.addListener in a chrome extension. So far I found http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/trunk/webNavigation.html and http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/experimental.webNavigation.html - which one is valid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`webNavigation` went stable in Chrome 16, which just landed minutes ago! http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/webNavigation.html

Answer (score 0):

The `webNavigation` API is still experimental. The first link has **/trunk/** in it which referes to the prerelease documentation matching Chrome Canary or Chromium. You can read more about the documentation versions [here](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/trunk/docs.html#versions). It looks like Chrome 17 is the planned milestone for `webNavigation` but that could get pushed back.